# Help with \newenvironment

Tags: environments

I am trying to make a new environment that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}

\newenvironment{program}{
\newcommand{\innslag}[3]{ \item{\textbf{##1} / \emph{##2} // ##3\} }
\begin{multicols}[2]{
\begin{description}
}
{
\end{description}
}
\end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{program}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
...etc
\end{program}

\end{document}
```

to re-produce this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{description}
\item \textbf{Heading 1} \emph{(Heading 2)}
    \\ Heading 3
\item \textbf{Heading 1} \emph{(Heading 2)}
    \\ Heading 3
\item \textbf{Heading 1} \emph{(Heading 2)}
    \\ Heading 3
\item \textbf{Heading 1} \emph{(Heading 2)}
    \\ Heading 3
\item \textbf{Heading 1} \emph{(Heading 2)}
    \\ Heading 3
\item \textbf{Heading 1} \emph{(Heading 2)}
    \\ Heading 3
\end{description}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

which should look like this:
[image: tex example]

But my LaTeX-Fu isn't there quite yet so i cant get my enviroment to work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to list all errors you make. `;-)`

Let me start with the correct solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\newenvironment{program}
 {% begin part
  \newcommand{\innslag}[3]{\item \textbf{##1} (\emph{##2})\\##3}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{description}
 }
 {% end part
  \end{description}
  \end{multicols}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{program}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\innslag{test1}{test}{test}
\end{program}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, I'm not sure why defining `\innslag` only inside the environment, but it's a possible stylistic choice.

Where did you go wrong?

1. `\item` doesn't take an argument.
2. `\item{\textbf{##1} / \emph{##2} // ##3\}` has an unwanted slash and an unwanted double slash; moreover `\}` doesn't balance the opening brace.
3. `\begin{multicols}[2]` is wrong: the number of columns is a mandatory argument
4. Opening a brace after `\begin{multicols}{2}` (after fixing the previous error) is wrong: `multicols` is an environment, so it doesn't take the text to be typeset in multiple columns as an argument.

Comment: Many thanks. Constructive and educational. It makes sense when seeing the correct way to do it. What did you mean about defining '\innslag' only inside the environment?

Comment: @Buschmann Don't you have `\newcommand` inside the “begin part”? The `\innslag` command will be undefined outside the `program` environment.

Comment: This is true. Would it be better to define it outside as well?

Comment: @Buschmann I see no problem in having it only available inside the environment, although I'd probably use a different strategy. Not a big deal, though.

Comment: When my chops advance perhaps I'll learn to do things more efficient. For now this will do the job. Thanks!